# how to simulate session end event using sql session state in server farm

Tags: sql, session-state, load-balancing

The session end event is not available when using SQL session state. We have an existing appication that uses this event, but we need to switch it over to SQL session state so we can set up a server farm for the application. We were hoping to use "sticky sessions" on the load balancer so we could keep using inproc session state, but were unable to get that working.

Has anyone faced a similar challenge or have any ideas?

THanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can crate a flag on the table that stores the session state and set it to a value to indicate the session is ended.

Comment: If the session expired the row gets removed from the sql session db table, so what good would a flag do? Plus i need access to the session object on session end.